# How change gmail setting to see the annotation in promotion tab?

Tags: html, gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I'm researching the annotation on promotion tab.When i send a test  to my email,but i can't see anything else in my promotion tab.Should i change some setting in gmail to show the annotations?Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work on the app and the email not in any group.

Answer (score 0):

The features are live in the Gmail App with desktop slotted to launch mid 2019 - it will be multiplatform soon.

All gmail.com accounts with default settings unchanged can see the features. Check these default settings: tabs and ads enabled, **Images: Always show**, **Conversation view: On**, and **Enable Bundling of Top Email: On** (some accounts may not have this last setting, if not ignore).

Comment: Thank you,where can I get the official Google news about it?